# I am taking fire. - What does it mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I am a bit confused now. "I am taking fire." - Does it mean that I am shooting someone or that someone is shooting me? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a militarian context, "taking fire" would mean being shot at, attacked:

> Send air support, we're taking heavy fire here!

**Other use cases:**

It can also be used in a more idiomatic manner in certain settings, to convey the idea that one is being critized.

> "I'm taking all the fire for a mistake that *you've* made."
>
> "John, Kerry's spokesperson, elected to take all the fire when he showed up to the press conference alone."

The ["dry" definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/take+fire) of "**take** fire" is:

> start to burn or burst into flames

Answer (score 2):

In the context of shooting/war, "taking fire" means someone is shooting at you.

This is similar to the phrase "[under fire](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/taking+fire)":

> 1.) Exposed or subjected to enemy attack.

However, the phrase usually refers to [catching fire](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/take+fire):

> Start to burn or burst into flames